# Copying the HTML code in Firefox' "No Style" view

Tags: html, firefox, styles

Some webpages get "better" when "No Style" is chosen in Firefox (*View > Page Style > No Style*): E.g. the text quickly reflows.

I need to save websites precisely the way they are rendered with "No Style". Is that possible? Can one copy the Firefox-transformed HTML code behind the "No Style" view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Web Developer is doing is something like this:

```js
function disableStyleSheets() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
        document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
}

function disableInlineStyles(node) {
    if (node.hasAttribute("style")) {
        node.setAttribute("data-style", node.getAttribute("style"));
        node.removeAttribute("style");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++)
        disableInlineStyles(node.children[i]);
}

disableStyleSheets();
disableInlineStyles(document.documentElement);
```

So it just disables all styles on the page to be able to re-enable them.

Though what you want is to remove the styles completely, so something like this:

```js
function removeInlineStyles(node) {
    if (node.hasAttribute("style"))
        node.removeAttribute("style");

    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++)
        removeInlineStyles(node.children[i]);
}

var styleSheets = document.querySelectorAll("style, link[type='text/css']");
for (var i = styleSheets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    styleSheets[i].parentNode.removeChild(styleSheets[i]);

removeInlineStyles(document.documentElement);
```

Execute that within Firebug's [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor).
Then you have three ways to save the source.

1. Inside the Web Developer toolbar choose *View Source* > *View Generated Source*.  In the upcoming dialog choose *File* > *Save Page As...* to save the contents to a file.
2. Focus the page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, right-click the page and choose *View Selection Source* from the context menu. In the upcoming dialog choose *File* > *Save Page As...* to save the contents to a file.
3. Within Firebug's [HTML panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) right-click the `<html>` element and choose *Copy HTML* from the context menu. Open a text editor, paste the contents from the clipboard and save the file.

Comment: An exquisite way! Thank you very much!